# Javascript appendChild onload event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, appendchild

I'm appending the dynamically created image element to document.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'test.jpg',
img.onload = function() {

    var addedImg = container.appendChild(img);
    console.log(img.width); //old width.
}
```

The problem here is the fact if I take image dimensions right after `container.appendChild(img)` it returns the source file dimensions because the appendChild has not finished yet(not repainted?) and dimensions are not re-calculated.

```
var addedImg = container.appendChild(img);
console.log(img.width) //returns original width of the image
```

So, I'm wondering if it is possible to catch the load event for appendChild?

I know it is possible using `setTimeout/setInterval`, but I guess there should be more elegant solution.

```
var addedImg = container.appendChild(img);
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(img.width); //return correct resolution after image dimensions were recalculated
}, 1000);
```

The problem with setTimeout/setInterval is the fact I don't know when element is finally appended and repainted. I have to run it on a loop.

I was trying to listen to `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` and `DOMNodeInserted` events however it does not work.

```
img.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", onImageInserted, false);
img.addEventListener("DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument", onImageInserted, false);

function onImageInserted(event) {
    console.log(img.width); //still wrong width
}
```

However, it seems to run right after appendChild is fired.

Here is the fiddle so you can see what I'm talking about: 
http://jsfiddle.net/0zyybmf2/

Note: please don't advise to check the width of the parent container. I need to take a width of the image.
Any help with this would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Images have a `load` event.

Comment: ex: `img.onload=function(){alert(this.naturalWidth)}`

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. This code is already inside img.load. This is about catching the repaint event.

Comment: `appendChild has not finished yet`,  what ?

Comment: Sorry guys that I was not clear enough. I updated the post with a fiddle so you can see it in action.

Comment: same with `setTimeout(fn..., 0)` like if the repaint was done right after your callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that you have to hand the controls back to the browser (using `setTimeout()` as you did) before the final dimensions can be observed; luckily, the timeout can be very short.

```
container.appendChild(img);
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(img.width);
}, 0);
```

In other words, the repaint (and layout update) is done as soon as your function returns and before the `setTimeout` fires.

Btw, it's advisable to only set the `.src` property *after* you've attached the load handler; I've had to debug my code a few times before I realised that cached images may trigger the load handler immediately upon changing `.src`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0zyybmf2/1/)

Comment: Thank you. But I'm aware of the `setTimeout`. I mentioned that in the original question. The problem with `setTimeout` is the fact I don't know when repaint it's fired. The only possible solution is to check if width was changed or not inside the setTimeout (I think `setInterval` would be even better for that). I'm wondering if there's another solution.

Comment: @Sray Well, you set the timeout value to 1 second, which is unnecessary; also, why would you need to know exactly when the repaint is done? it's done as soon as your function finishes, that's the whole point.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you for the perfect explanation.

Comment: There's no need of setTimeout. Refer my answer.

Comment: @NK Yeah, but in your answer you see the image load before the alert is shown, that might not be what OP wants.

Comment: @Ja͢ck, 2 points. First,in your solution also, image is loaded before logged in to console (try put an alert instead to make sure). Second, if you subscribe onload event after setting src to the image element, it will not always works fine.

Comment: @NK I said that in your answer the image loading is *visible to the user* whereas only adding the image when the loading is complete will make the image appear immediately; I've mentioned your second point in my answer as well.

Comment: @Ja͢ck, well... convinced.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var img = new Image();
var container = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
container.appendChild(img);

img.onload = function() {
  alert('Width = ' + img.width);
}

img.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/600/400";
```

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As 2022 [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) can be a solution.

```js
const callback = ( mutations, mutationObserver ) => {
   mutationObserver.disconnect();
   const MutationRecord = [...mutations];
   console.log( MutationRecord );
};

let mutationObserver = new MutationObserver( callback );

mutationObserver.observe( document.querySelector( "#mmp-map-2b40f571" ), { childList: true, subtree: false } );

document.querySelector( "#mmp-map-2b40f571" ).appendChild( document.createElement( "div" ) );
```

```html
<div id="mmp-map-2b40f571"></div>
```