# dynamically add canvas for chart.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to display a dynamic number of charts on a webpage. The number of charts will vary depending on the number of ' daemon services'. I create the canvas for each. however when I attempt to draw the chart only the last one renders. All of the canvases are written to the document but are blank.

Here is my javascript:

```
var specContainer = document.getElementById("SpecificContainer");
        daemonCanvases = [];
        daemonCharts = [];
        for (var i=0;i<data.services.length;i++) {
            specContainer.innerHTML += '<div><canvas id="' + data.services[i] + '"></canvas></div>';
            var daemonCanv = document.getElementById(data.services[i]).getContext('2d');

            daemonCanvases.push(daemonCanv);

            daemonCharts.push(new Chart(daemonCanvases[i], {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: timeSpanLabels,
                    datasets: myDataSets,
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: false,
                }
            }));
        }
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="display">
    <div id="SpecificContainer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is create canvas node programatically as below and attach.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.id = "my-id";
specContainerNode.appendChild(canvas);

// ----- more code ------ 

 setTimeout(function() {
  /* TIP: This timeout will be helpful to execute logic after a repaint.
          Thus, this block will execute only after nodes were attached */

      // ----- more code -----

 }, 0);
```

See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669535/javascript-appendchild-onload-event) for more info.

Comment: it's recommended that the timeout be greater than 0, and recommended to be larger than the js clock tick. I usually use `100`ms, but `10`ms should be enough.